# JList - getting value from Click

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

Is there any way to use ListSelectionListener or MouseAdapter to get information about selected value (if value is a String for example), is there any built-in method for that?

I only know how to get proper indexes but not the content or content.toString()

I'm adding element like this:

```
{
    DefaultListModel listModel;

    listModel.addElement(name);
}
```

@Edit 
Thank you for you for help.
I solved my problem by doing this (for future generations so they wouldn't need to search as I did):

> ```
>     list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
>           @Override
>           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
>               System.out.println("Mouse click.");
>               int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
>               System.out.println("Index Selected: " + index);
>               String s = (String) list.getSelectedValue();
>               System.out.println("Value Selected: " + s.toString());
>           }
>     });
> ```

Comment: Try [JList#getSelectedValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValue%28%29) and read more [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

Answer (score 5):

When using a `JList` you can simply use [JList#getSelectedValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValue%28%29) which will return the actual object that is current selected.

If you are doing this from within a `MouseListener`, it would be better to use [`JList#locationToIndex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#locationToIndex%28java.awt.Point%29) and then get the value from the `JList` using it's index

```
 String value = (String)list.getModel().getElementAt(list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint()));
```