# Get the selected Object from the List

Tags: java, swing, jlist, mouselistener

It's my first time using `MouseListener` and I don't know how to implement it.

Here's the code:

```
 DefaultListModel<Object> listModel = new DefaultListModel<Object>();
 try {
listModel = readLines(file);
    //this function basically converts the file in a defaultlistmodel
 } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
 }

  JList<Object> list = new JList<Object>();
  list.setModel(listModel);
  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
  list.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
  list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
  scrollPane.setBounds(10, 21, 130, 267);
  westPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

What I want is to create a mouse listener, that when I click an `Object` from the list (scroll pane), save it (`getElementAt(index)`) and implement it elsewhere, like in a different text field.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234740/jlist-getting-value-from-click

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JList - getting value from Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234740/jlist-getting-value-from-click)

Comment: 1) **Don't** use a `MouseListener` on a `JList`. Instead use a [`ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) built for the task. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) `scrollPane.setBounds(10, 21, 130, 267);` That'll come back to bite you in the butt. Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  ..

Comment: .. As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 4) *"What I want is.."* What this **needs** is a question. What *is* your question?

Comment: Solved the problem, ty. @AndrewThompson about the AbsoluteLayout, I know. But my software is kinda complex and I need it done in time. I used other layout as much as i could...but in some places it was like impossible for me to make it work. Let's hope for the best!

Comment: *"..but in some places it was like impossible for me to make it work."* Is the code using combinations of layouts as linked above? *"..I need it done in time"* Is this for a one-off project of 'toss away' code? If there's any chance of continued use or changes to the GUI later, it will work out easier (faster) to use layouts from the get-go.

Comment: *Solved the problem,* - then "accept" Andrews answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

*Don't* use a `MouseListener` on a `JList`. Instead use a [`ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) built for the task.

Here's a short example I put together before realising you'd solved the problem just based on that tip. So I'm posting it anyway. 😉

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class FontSelector {

    FontSelector() {
        JPanel fontSelectorPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.
                getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        String[] fonts = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
        final JList fontList = new JList(fonts);
        fontSelectorPanel.add(new JScrollPane(fontList));
        fontList.setCellRenderer(new FontCellRenderer());
        fontList.setVisibleRowCount(10);

        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(
                "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.", 3, 20);
        fontSelectorPanel.add(new JScrollPane(
                textArea), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);

        ListSelectionListener fontListener = (ListSelectionEvent e) -> {
            String fontName = fontList.getSelectedValue().toString();
            textArea.setFont(new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 50));
        };
        fontList.addListSelectionListener(fontListener);
        fontList.setSelectedIndex(0);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fontSelectorPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new FontSelector();
        });
    }
}

class FontCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list,
            Object value,
            int index,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(
                list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        Font font = new Font((String) value, Font.PLAIN, 20);
        label.setFont(font);
        return label;
    }
}
```